# Why XCode says a method is deprecated in cocos2d v2.0?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, deprecated

I have this code in my app, byt xcode says its deprecated.

```
CCMenuItemSprite *imageButton = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"button_unselected.png"] selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"button_selected.png"] disabledSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"button_disabled.png"] target:self selector:@selector(buttonTouched:)];
```

I jumped to definition and found this:

```
+(id) itemWithNormalSprite:(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol>*)normalSprite selectedSprite:(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol>*)selectedSprite
{
    return [self itemWithNormalSprite:normalSprite selectedSprite:selectedSprite disabledSprite:nil target:nil selector:nil];
}
```

And it doesnt say deprecated.  Why would this happen?

Comment: this is not the definition (.h) but the implementation (.m). Check that and ccdeprecated.h/.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in newer virsion of cocos2d some method's name has been changed so that some times xcode will give you that method is deprecated.

```
CCMenuItemSprite *imageButton = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"button_unselected.png"] selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"button_selected.png"] disabledSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"button_disabled.png"] target:self selector:@selector(buttonTouched:)];
```